# How to disable a hotkey only if the active window is a given size?

Tags: automation, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

I want to disable <kbd>Shift</kbd> only if the active window is 500px wide and 300px tall, how to write such a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easily doable with a context sensitive hotkey with `#If`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)</sup>.

```
#If, SizeCheck()
RShift::
LShift::return
#If

SizeCheck()
{
    WinGetPos, , , width, height, A
    return width == 500 && height == 300
}
```

Be sure to add the `*` modifier<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard)</sup> as you see fit.